# Is it possible for webpack to automatically register index files for a given directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm wondering if, instead of building index files manually, ie. if I have a directory of 'Helper' classes, or Repositories, and I would prefer to import/use them like:

import { UserHelper, GroupHelper } from 'src/helpers';

Can webpack automatically generate the /src/helpers/index.js file which would export each Helper file within that directory automatically? Or should I have to manually create the index file myself?

Thanks,
Ryan